# Search in joined table with multiple records

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a table 'contacts' which is structured like this:

- id, name, surname, etc

And contacts_related

- contact_id, name, surname

One contact can have multiple related contacts (joined by contact_id). What I would like to do is make a SELECT query on contacts that if a search input is given (example: 'John') it prints all contacts that have John in name OR contacts that have a related contact with 'John' in the name.

Any suggestions on how to do this, without making two distinct queries?

Comment: Why do you have two tables both storing the same kind of thing (name,surname)?

Comment: SELECT * FROM contact a LEFT JOIN related_contacts b ON a.id = b.contact_id HAVING a.name = 'JOHN' OR b.name = 'JOHN'

Comment: You may want to reconsider your table design. I'd suggest having one table storing `id`, `name`, `surname` and another with two `id`s (to reference the person 1 and person 2 who know eachother), you may then want to add another field such as `relationship`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution is

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT C.*
FROM 
    contacts C LEFT JOIN contacts_related R
    ON C.id=R.contact_id
WHERE
    C.name LIKE '%John%' OR 
    R.name LIKE '%John%'
```

Answer (score 0):

You want those contacts that are either Johns themselves or have a John relation. To look up the relations use EXISTS or IN.

```
select * 
from contacts
where name like '%John%'
or exists
(
  select *
  from contacts_related
  where name like '%John%'
  and contact_id = contacts.id
);
```

Or:

```
select * 
from contacts
where name like '%John%'
or id in
(
  select contact_id
  from contacts_related
  where name like '%John%'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
select a.id,a.name,a.surname from 
contacts a join contacts_related b 
on SOUNDEX(a.name)=SOUNDEX(a.name)
```

or

```
select a.id,a.name,a.surname from 
contacts a, contacts_related b 
where SOUNDEX(a.name)=SOUNDEX(b.name)
```

select column according to your need.

Answer (score 0):

Below is your answer,  i have tested and its working!!!

```
SELECT c.name 
FROM contact T
    INNER JOIN contact_r C ON C.Id = T.id
WHERE C.name LIKE '%saif%'
```

data in contact Table
[image]

data in contact_r Table:
[image]